# Are function parameters given local address space if not explicitly defined?

Tags: c, x86, stack

Here's a simple program:

simple.c

```
int inverse(int input)
{
  if( input == 0 )
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  inverse(1);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is:

Does `inverse()` push a local copy of the parameter named

```
int input
```

or does it just keep referencing the parameter each time it is accessed?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "explicitly defined".  But in practice, the compiler is likely to optimise this to use no extra stack space at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep in mind. `int input` definition is local to the function `inverse()`. So each time `inverse()` is called, stack space for `input` is allocated separately and once `inverse()` has finished execution, there will be no existence of `input` variable.

<sup>* Without any compiler optimization</sup>

Comment: In regards to optimization, main has to push the parameter before calling `inverse()` anyway; would it not be more efficient to access `[ebp + 8]` than to create another instance of a variable? I understand that `int input` is instructing to create a new local variable. @Sourav

Comment: With compiler optimization, it could pass input in a register, or it could eliminate the call to inverse completely since it's return value is never used.

Answer (score 1):

The caller of the function inverse provides values for all the parameters. The function inverse then turns these values into local variables, just as if you had declared

```
int input;
```

inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Variables that are declared inside a function or block are called local variables. They can be used only by statements that are inside that function or block of code. Local variables are not known to functions outside their own.

In this case, `int input` is a local variable.

After the execution is finished, there will not be a reference to the variable `int input`. +1 for @Sourav's tip about the compiler optimization.